# delete duplicate records from MYSQL Table no unique column yet

Tags: mysql

I know this has been asked before but cant get the code to work on my table.

I have a table `products`

as follows

```
    products_id  products_model   ect
    1            abc              blah
    1            abc              blah
    2            def              blah
    2            def              blah
```

and so on,

I will make the products_id unique but for now i have duplicates based upon the product_id column.

how can I get rid of any duplicates, I dont care which one just need rid of them.

thankyou.

Comment: What queries have you tried? This doesn't show much [research effort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) IMO.

Comment: You can copy non-duplicate entries in another table, rename this to `products_backup` and then rename the new table to `products`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to execute this statement,

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE products ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (products_id)
```

Comment: thanks that worked and the duplicates are gone too. thanks very much

Comment: ill tick your answer box in a moment. too soon. :)

Comment: the only issue with this solution is if he has (actually, based on his comment HAD :D) different products under the same ID, not just 100% identical duplicates. like. ID=1, products_model="uncleFoo". he then lost a product or two :P

Comment: @Mark you're right but it is not possible to have the same product id with different name, right?

Comment: @JW웃 your answer was perfect. What I meant is, as John said he is new to this area it is possible he may didn't take that option into account when seen there's no key in table but there are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to:

```
insert into products_unique
select distinct * 
from products
```

Comment: would that delete the records or move them ? sorry very new to mysql

Comment: I have a statement that works to see the duplicates just not sure how to get rid of them

Comment: Actually MySQL doesn't support [SELECT INTO TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)...

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE `tmp` like `ect`;

INSERT INTO tmp (`products_id`, `products_model`, `ect`)
SELECT `products_id`, `products_model`, `ect`
    FROM `PRODUCT`
    GROUP BY `products_id`;

RENAME TABLE `product` to `deleteme`, `tmp` to `product`;